# javascript file that recognizes that I am on a specific url and prints a statement in the console

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding using javascript and I am currently trying to write a javascript file that recognizes that I am on a specific url then it will console log a message like 'You are on url:[example].'

The purpose of the script is to recognize when I navigate to the specific url. Once I go to that url it will print a statement in the console. How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Read some docs, tutorials and/or blogs and then provide some code showing what you attempted to do and what your problem in the code is.

Answer (score 0):

```
const currentPage = document.location.href
console.log(currentPage)
```